# Measure time spent in TCP stack by packets/segments

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, hook

For the incoming TCP segments, I would like to measure the time interval between the moment when TCP segment becomes available to the kernel (coming from the NIC's driver) and the moment when the same segment becomes available to a user level application via socket api (after it passed through the TCP stack).

To simplify the problem I am sending infrequent packets over TCP  and the network is pretty stable, thus you can assume that there is 1 to 1 mapping between a TCP segment and the logical application level packet/message that I send.

**Kernel level timestamps:**

To obtain the first kernel level timestamp as segments arrives, I used netfilter's NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING hook, and read the timestamp from skbuff, this part seems to work fine.

**User level timestamps:**

However, I am having difficulties obtaining the precise measurement of the moment in time when message (a corresponding buffer) is available to be read from the socket. The problem is that the time when  the user level application calls `read` does not strictly correlates with the time when buffer is available. For example, if the system is under load, the intervals between consequative read calls from the application will increase. Thus, by the time I read a buffer and timestamp it (at the application level), this time will not correspond to the time when that buffer was actually ready to be read.

Therefore, is there a way that I can obtaine a precise timestamp of the moment when the TCP stack is done processing  a segment? Perhaps there are some other kernel hooks that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: For investigational purposes, you could run your receiving process under a realtime priority (see `sched_setscheduler`), which will prevent other ordinary user processes from preempting it. But there may still be "unmeasurable" small latencies between the time the buffer is ready to be read, and the time the process is resumed and is able to complete the read/recv call. Anything more (afaik) would require instrumentation in the kernel (and I know of kernel hooks that would help here).

Comment: @Gil Hamilton, thank you for your suggestion regarding the realtime scheduler. I looked into it, but I in my particular case it will not fit well because the process that reads the TCP stream also does some computation work, which will inherit the run-time priority (I omitted this part in my question). Could you please point out some of the hooks that you think might be relevant and I will go from here. Thanks!

Comment: Doh. Sorry, typo. I meant to say "I know of *no* kernel hooks..."

Comment: sure, no problem :)